# CDH Hive raise: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

Tags: hive, cloudera

I installed `CDH 6.2` on two servers, device1 is the master.
There was no any errors in CM web UI, however, when I run hive command-line: `show databaes;` in device1, there was an Exception as below:

```
dennis@device1:~$ hive
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/bin/../lib/hive/conf/hive-env.sh: line 24: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/hbase/hbase-hadoop2-compat.jar: Permission denied
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/bin/../lib/hive/conf/hive-env.sh: line 25: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/hbase/lib/htrace-core.jar: Permission denied
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/bin/../lib/hive/conf/hive-env.sh: line 26: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/hbase/hbase-common.jar: Permission denied
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/bin/../lib/hive/conf/hive-env.sh: line 27: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/hbase/hbase-server.jar: Permission denied
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/bin/../lib/hive/conf/hive-env.sh: line 28: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/hbase/hbase-hadoop-compat.jar: Permission denied
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/bin/../lib/hive/conf/hive-env.sh: line 29: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/hbase/hbase-protocol.jar: Permission denied
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/bin/../lib/hadoop/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2331: HADOOP_ORG.APACHE.HADOOP.HBASE.UTIL.GETJAVAPROPERTY_USER: bad substitution
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/bin/../lib/hadoop/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2426: HADOOP_ORG.APACHE.HADOOP.HBASE.UTIL.GETJAVAPROPERTY_OPTS: bad substitution
WARNING: Use "yarn jar" to launch YARN applications.
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/jars/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.8.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/jars/hive-common-2.1.1-cdh6.2.0.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: false

WARNING: Hive CLI is deprecated and migration to Beeline is recommended.
hive> show databases;
FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
hive>
```

However, there is no any Exception on the device2 when I run hive command-line.
Besides, it is also normal on `Hue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't have a Gateway for the Hive service on your device1, only on your device2, which probably also has the Hive MetaStore. See also [How Hive Configurations are Propagated to Hive Clients](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/cm_mc_hive_service.html#xd_583c10bfdbd326ba-204beb9-13ef1573a9e--7ff6__section_gmq_nq5_hl) (emphasis mine):

> Because the Hive service does not have worker roles, another mechanism is needed to enable the propagation of client configurations to the other hosts in your cluster. In Cloudera Manager gateway roles fulfill this function. Whether you add a Hive service at installation time or at a later time, ensure that you assign the gateway roles to hosts in the cluster. **If you do not have gateway roles, client configurations are not deployed.**

Your device1 doesn't have the client configuration and therefore can't establish a connection with the Hive MetaStore.

You should also check the error messages you get at the start of your copied output (emphasis mine):

> /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/bin/../lib/hive/conf/hive-env.sh: line 24: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/hbase/hbase-hadoop2-compat.jar: **Permission denied**

There may be permission problems with the hive user not being able to access certain directories.

And a last point is that you should switch to beeline. As the following message from your output shows the Hive CLI is not recommended:

> WARNING: Hive CLI is deprecated and migration to Beeline is recommended.

See also [Migrating from Hive CLI to Beeline: A Primer](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/02/migrating-from-hive-cli-to-beeline-a-primer/), a guide from Cloudera fom 2014:

> Recently, the Hive community (with Cloudera engineers leading the charge) introduced HiveServer2, an enhanced Hive server designed for multi-client concurrency and improved authentication that also provides better support for clients connecting through JDBC and ODBC. Now HiveServer2, with Beeline as the command-line interface, is the recommended solution; HiveServer1 and Hive CLI are deprecated and the latter won’t even work with HiveServer2.

Comment: Thanks Secespitus, I solved it by changing the hive-site.xml on device1 to default config, as I modified the config before without notice.

Comment: now I'm puzzled about permission problem. after I chmod 777 to hbase-hadoop2-compat.jar, there is messy code when starting hive cli:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0/lib/hbase/hbase-hadoop2-compat.jar: line 1: $'PK\003\004': command not found
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/hbase/hbase-hadoop2-compat.jar: line 2: K6nN: command not found
K-*όϳR0ҳᤲ,Jψ,K-䣖+9RKRSt*­-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/hbase/hbase-hadoop2-compat.jar: line 3:J6nN¥o·META-INF/MANIFEST.MFLK-.
                         3R: No such file or directory

Comment: @DennisLi That does indeed look quite messy. I don't know right now what exactly the problem there is. Some files seem to be missing. In general it's not a good idea to use "chmod 777". Instead you should check out which differences there are between device1 and device2. Which permissions do the files referenced in all your error messages and the directories these reside in have? Are all of them present on both systems? Are there any other differences between the two servers, for example different services installed (Gateways, Hive-Server2, Hive MetaStore, ...)?

Comment: @DennisLi You should check whether you are having the same problems with beeline instead of the Hive CLI. It wouldn't surprise me if that old thing had some really weird problems by now. But do you still get the error message when executing "show databases;"?

Comment: just the same as running with beeline.  There is no error executing "show databases" now :)

Comment: @DennisLi Hmm... If it's working I would ignore the permission stuff for now. Apparently it's not crucial for everything to work, but keep those errors in mind if you run into some other problems with Hive. It might be related.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196856/discussion-between-dennisli-and-secespitus).

Comment: @DennisLi Sorry, can't use the chat right now. I'll check it out later though. Good luck with your project anyways, if there are new errors it might be a good idea to ask a new question on StackOverflow specifically for that.

Comment: there seemed to make not any difference except a permission warning. thanks for your help:)

Comment: I've faced the same problem. Seems like Hive is working correctly (because I'm not working with HBase) but these errors are confusing...

Comment: I've added gateways on each server but it didn't help.

Comment: @VeLKerr Depending on your situation it might be better to ask a new question to put all the details in there. What you could check is that you have 1) Installed the Gateway and re-deployed the configurations 2) don't have any permission problems on the OS level with the user executing the command 3) didn't have any errors when installing with Cloudera Manager 4) have the newest version installed that is available 5) are using Beeling instead of Hive CLI  - The most important one of these is 2), as the user that is *executing the command* might be different from the standard Hive user *hive*